# Translate C++ Code (com interface) to C#

Tags: c#, com

I am trying to write a DirectSound Wrapper. So I have to import the Cominterfaces of the dsound.h file to c#. I am currently working on IDirectSoundBuffer. This is declared like this:

```
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IDirectSoundBuffer, 0x279AFA85, 0x4981, 0x11CE, 0xA5, 0x21, 0x00, 0x20, 0xAF, 0x0B, 0xE5, 0x60);

#undef INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE IDirectSoundBuffer

DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IDirectSoundBuffer, IUnknown)
{
    // IUnknown methods
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)       (THIS_ __in REFIID, __deref_out LPVOID*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)        (THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)       (THIS) PURE;

    // IDirectSoundBuffer methods
    STDMETHOD(GetCaps)              (THIS_ __out LPDSBCAPS pDSBufferCaps) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetCurrentPosition)   (THIS_ __out_opt LPDWORD pdwCurrentPlayCursor, __out_opt LPDWORD pdwCurrentWriteCursor) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetFormat)            (THIS_ __out_bcount_opt(dwSizeAllocated) LPWAVEFORMATEX pwfxFormat, DWORD dwSizeAllocated, __out_opt LPDWORD pdwSizeWritten) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVolume)            (THIS_ __out LPLONG plVolume) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetPan)               (THIS_ __out LPLONG plPan) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetFrequency)         (THIS_ __out LPDWORD pdwFrequency) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetStatus)            (THIS_ __out LPDWORD pdwStatus) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Initialize)           (THIS_ __in LPDIRECTSOUND pDirectSound, __in LPCDSBUFFERDESC pcDSBufferDesc) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Lock)                 (THIS_ DWORD dwOffset, DWORD dwBytes,
                                           __deref_out_bcount(*pdwAudioBytes1) LPVOID *ppvAudioPtr1, __out LPDWORD pdwAudioBytes1,
                                           __deref_opt_out_bcount(*pdwAudioBytes2) LPVOID *ppvAudioPtr2, __out_opt LPDWORD pdwAudioBytes2, DWORD dwFlags) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Play)                 (THIS_ DWORD dwReserved1, DWORD dwPriority, DWORD dwFlags) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetCurrentPosition)   (THIS_ DWORD dwNewPosition) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetFormat)            (THIS_ __in LPCWAVEFORMATEX pcfxFormat) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetVolume)            (THIS_ LONG lVolume) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetPan)               (THIS_ LONG lPan) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetFrequency)         (THIS_ DWORD dwFrequency) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Stop)                 (THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Unlock)               (THIS_ __in_bcount(dwAudioBytes1) LPVOID pvAudioPtr1, DWORD dwAudioBytes1,
                                           __in_bcount_opt(dwAudioBytes2) LPVOID pvAudioPtr2, DWORD dwAudioBytes2) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Restore)              (THIS) PURE;
};
```

So I tried to Translate this like this:

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
Guid("279AFA85-4981-11CE-A521-0020AF0BE560")]
public interface IDirectSoundBuffer : IUnknown
{
    //int QueryInterface(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr comObject);
    //int AddReference();
    //int Release();

    //IDirectSoundBuffer methods
    void GetCaps([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DSBufferCaps pDSBufferCaps); //TODO
    void GetCurrentPosition([Out] out UInt32 pdwCurrentPlayCursor, [Out] out UInt32 pdwCurrentWriteCursor);
    void GetFormat([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalType = "AMEngine.Wave.WaveFormatMarshaler")] out AMEngine.Wave.WaveFormat pwfxFormat,
                    int dwSizeAllocated, [Out] out int pdwSizeWritten); //TODO implement
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4) /*See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx */]
    Int32 GetVolume();
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    Int32 GetPan();
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    Int32 GetFrequency();
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    Int32 GetStatus();
    void Initialize([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDirectSound pDirectSound, [In] DSBufferDescription pcDSBufferDesc);
    void Lock(int dwOffset, int dwBytes,
              [Out] out IntPtr ppvAudioPtr1, [Out] out int pdwAudioBytes1,
              [Out] out IntPtr ppvAudioPtr2, [Out] out int pdwAudioBytes2,
              DSBLock dwFlags );
    void Play(int dwReserved1, int dwPriority, DSBPlayFlags dwFlags); 
    void SetCurrentPosition(int dwNewPosition);
    void SetFormat([In] AMEngine.Wave.WaveFormat pcfxFormat);
    void SetVolume(int lVolume);
    void SetPan(int lPan);
    void SetFrequency(int dwFrequency);
    void Stop();
    void Unlock([In] IntPtr pvAudioPtr1, int dwAudioBytes1,
                [In] IntPtr pvAudioPtr2, int dwAudioBytes2);
    void Restore();

}
```

IUnknown is this Interface:

```
[Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface IUnknown
{
    int QueryInterface(ref Guid gidd, out IntPtr ppvObject);
    int AddRef();
    int Release();
}
```

The Interface IDirectSoundBuffer itself works. But for some members like SetVolume I got an exception E_NONINTERFACE and it told me that I have to implement QueryInterface. So I created IUnknown. But I can try what ever I like. It never works. When I try the solution above I get an exception when I try to play a primary buffer. It tells me that I have to set other flags to the primarybufferdescritption. But I if I set other flags I get an exception that when i try to create the buffer. 
In the end I came to the result that something with the interface declaration has to be wrong because if i remove all IUnknown stuff I can play audio but I just can t set the volume, pan,... BUT i can play it and it works so FAR.

I am trying to solve this problem since a few weeks but I can t find any solution. So you are my last hope :(

Comment: Your translation contains a lot of mistakes.  There's little point in trying to tackle this yourself, it has been done before.  Take a look at SharpDX.

Comment: I ve took a look at sharpdx but it is not that what i am looking for. (i also had a look on slimdx). 

Sharpdx is doing that an other way. The author wrote to me:

"Oh, i see, most part of the source ode is generated directly from DirectX C++ headers at built time. In each project, there is a generated folder with the generated files." But I really can t find those generated files. And the whole project is much more complex as I need it. He wrote some kind of translator for headerfiles because he needs much more interfaces. So could you may tell me my mistaces?